# Getting List of Files From Directory Into ComboBox

Tags: c#, combobox

Using C#, I want to get the list of files in a folder.
My goal inside a combo box:

```
File1.txt
File2.txt
File3.txt
```

Process works when using `Console.WriteLine` however can't convert the string into the object, see below.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
foreach(string file in files)
    ComboBox.Items.AddRange(Path.GetFileName(file));
```

Help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Convert the string into what object?  You should be able to simply add the items to the list of items for the combobox.   There are plenty of examples on how to do this.

Comment: This should work:
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(files);

Comment: Thanks B. Clay Shannon, I have tried but it cant convert the string[] to an object

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with your `foreach`, you just need to change `AddRange` to `Add`:

```
foreach (string filePath in files) comboBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(filePath));
```

Here is another way using the LINQ extension method [IEnumerable.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891) like this:

```
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(files.Select((string filePath) => Path.GetFileName(filePath)).ToArray());
```